Lucene LowerCaseFilter does not work with KeywordAnalyser
It happens that some users use capital letters in their emails, e.g. John.Doe@fake.com. But we want to search using the whole email, but not case sensitive, so both searched emails (John.Doe@fake.com or john.doe@fake.com) should return the same user entity.
Our entity class with analyser definition looks like this
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER")
@Indexed
@AnalyzerDefs({
  @AnalyzerDef(
      name = "lowercaseKeywordAnalyzer",
      tokenizer = @TokenizerDef(factory = KeywordTokenizerFactory.class),
      filters = {@TokenFilterDef(factory = LowerCaseFilterFactory.class)})
})
public class UserDBVO {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "USER_ID")
  @Field(name = "id", analyzer = @Analyzer(impl = KeywordAnalyzer.class))
  private long userId;

  @NotNull
  @Column(name = "FIRST_NAME")
  @Field(name = "firstName")
  private String firstName;

  @NotNull
  @Column(name = "LAST_NAME")
  @Field(name = "lastName")
  private String lastName;

  @Column(name = "EMAIL", unique = true, length = 191)
  @Field(
      name = "email",
      analyzer = @Analyzer(definition = "lowercaseKeywordAnalyzer"))
  private String email;

  // ...
}

But unfortunately it doesn't work as expected. It looks like it doesn't take into account the LowerCaseFilter.
The index definition for this entity (sample) by making a call via Kibana dev console:
GET /fake.model.user

responses with this:
{
  "fake.model.user": {
    "aliases": {},
    "mappings": {
      "fake.model.User": {
        "properties": {
          "email": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
,
          "firstName": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "id": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "lastName": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
...

Any ideas how to make this working?
Versions:
org.hibernate.hibernate-search-engine:5.10.13.Final-redhat-00001
Thank you

I am unable to recreate your problem using the code in your question. Your code works correctly for me. I see the analyzer is added to the index correctly, with both the lowercase and keyword components. I get 2 results as expected when I create records using John.Doe@fake.com and john.doe@fake.com when I search for JOhN.dOe@faKe.coM. I am using a POM containing <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId> and <version>5.10.13.Final</version> with two artifacts: hibernate-search-orm and hibernate-search-elasticsearch.

(If my notes about the POM dependencies do not help you, you would need to provide more details to allow us to recreate the problem you are facing. I confess I have never used the dependency you mention at the end of your question.)
